# Spark to Hbase using Oozie

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, oozie

I was trying to create a table in Hbase from Spark and insert data, read data from it.

It works fine when I run the spark job from command line. But, It is throwing different types of exceptions each time I try to run it using oozie.

Here is my spark hbase code

```
    val sc = new SparkContext("local", "Hbase spark")

    val tableName = "Morbidity_Dummy2"

    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    // Add local HBase conf
    conf.addResource(new Path("file:///opt/cloudera/....../hbase-site.xml"))
    conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)

//     create m7 table with column family
    val admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf)
    if(!admin.isTableAvailable(tableName)) {
      print("Creating GHbase Table")
      val tableDesc = new HTableDescriptor(tableName)
      tableDesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("cf1"
                                    .getBytes()))
      admin.createTable(tableDesc)

    }else{
      print("Table already exists!!")
    }

    //put data into table
    val myTable = new HTable(conf, tableName)
    for (i <- 414540 to 414545) {

      var p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(""+i))
      p.add("cf1".getBytes(), "morbidity_score".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(""+(i*5)))
      p.add("cf1".getBytes(), "effective_date".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes("2016-07-01"))
      p.add("cf1".getBytes(), "cmi_id".getBytes(), Bytes.toBytes(""+i))

      myTable.put(p)
    }

    myTable.flushCommits()
//  create rdd
    val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], 
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])

    //get the row count
    val count = hBaseRDD.count()
    print("HBase RDD count:"+count)
    System.exit(0)
```

Here are the exceptions that I got

```
Exception1:    org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
Exception2:    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/exceptions/TimeoutIOException
Exception3:    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseIOException
```

I have also included `hbase-0.90.2.jar` and `hbase-client-1.2.1.jar` in the lib folder along with the spark jar. I don't understand why it is working from command line but not from oozie.

Comment: I think you're having issues with oozie job...Have you tried to use sharelib property of oozie workflow, oozie.action.sharelib.for.java=spark,hcatalog,hive,pig,atlas,hbase

Answer (score 1):

> Exception2:    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/exceptions/TimeoutIOException
>
> Exception3:    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseIOException

You need to add the hbase-common jar. (Try version [1.1.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-common/1.1.2))

Can you make sure you have these jars.

```
hbase-procedure-1.1.2.jar
hbase-server-1.1.2.jar
hbase-common-1.1.2.jar
hbase-client-1.1.2.jar
hbase-protocol-1.1.2.jar
```

This is a bit of trial and error process. You need to find the respective jar for a class and add to the classpath.

Comment: I added the hbase-common jar. I got a new exception now  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/protobuf/generated/MasterProtos$MasterService$BlockingInterface

Comment: I added all the above jars. But still I am getting other exceptions

Comment: Also, I don't understand why it is working fine from the command line but not from oozie.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you add all *.jar in HBASE_HOME folder to the library folder in Oozie. (JARs present in the HBASE_HOME folder and HBASE_HOME/lib -> to lib folder in Oozie)

The reason it must be working in your command line is because HBASE_HOME environment must have already been setup.